# Leg deforms awkwardly when in a crouching position

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

I've started learning armatures and have repeatedly attempted to make them only to get stuck with this problem.

[image]

[image]

Here is my topology. I don't see any superficial problem since I have only used quads. I have tried tinkering with weight paint but to no avail. What do I have to do to fix this?
[image]

Comment: I think it has to do with the assignment of weights of the mesh to the bones. Could you add a screenshot of the weights assigned to the upper legbone and lower legbone?

Comment: I agree with @FacebFaceb. It will be very helpful for us to help you if you upload the .blend file ;)